# XMPP client with OTR support for Mac OS X

Tags: open-source, osx, chat, xmpp

I'm looking for an open source/Free Software XMPP client which is running on Mac OS X.

I tried Gajim, but didn't get it running due to issues with Gtk. Somehow I'm not satisfied with Adium.

If the client is supporting more than XMPP it's fine, but no need or anything. A quite important thing would be support for OTR, optional omemo.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different clients you can use.

First one is [Adium](https://adium.im/), which is around for quite some time and supports XMPP and much more (like AIM, Yahoo, GChat...) and has OTR support.

Second one is [Tor Messenger](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-messenger-010b6-released). It's a fork of Instantbird (Mozilla's chat client) and has support for XMPP and OTR. Also it gives you an extra layer of security with using Tor to connect. It's currently in beta stage but so far everyone I know uses it without any problem on OS X (I'm using it on Ubuntu and Windows 10).

If you want more security and have no problem with using a beta software, go with Tor Messenger. But if you're looking for something stable, I'll recommend Adium.

Comment: Will give it a try but Tor is not adding any security, just anonymity.